# reading the position of a switch using a microcontroller

Tags: switches

I would like to use a micro controller to read the position of a switch.

The example and image below is for illustration purposes only.

For example if a switch is at Position A, a 5V signal might feed DIGITAL INPUT 1. Similarly if the switch is at Position B, a 5V signal might feed DIGITAL INPUT 2. To make the signals useful, they would be on exclusivity to the other.

i.e.

```
Position A   Position B   |   DIGITAL 1      DIGITAL 2
--------------------------|----------------------------
    ON          OFF       |     HIGH          LOW
                          |
    OFF         ON        |     LOW           HIGH
```

The circuit is powered by the micro controller's 5V supply, and shares a common ground with the micro controller.

Thank you.

EDIT: changed R1 (1 kOhm) to a DC motor, to better represent the actual circuit.

Also, the input voltage has an error or +-0.5V. The resistors have a 5% error tolerance.

[image]
https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/wec9n2/switch-sensing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I was drawing the schematic with a DPDT switch, Pete had beat me to the answer.

[image]

Comment: Say I wanted to add a third switch position with another resistor. Do switches with 3 throws like this exist?

Comment: [found some](http://goo.gl/7Cmx9)

Answer (score 4):

If you can, replace the switch with a DPDT switch, and use the second pole to feed a digital input pin.  In this case the second pole could be used to switch +5V or groud to the digital device input.

If you can not, you could use an [instrumentation amp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_amplifier) to sense the current through one or both resistors, setting the gain so that the output is a logic high level when the motor is drawing current through the resistor and is a logic low if not.  (Being careful not to overdrive the digital input level.)

Comment: Why use an instrumentation amplifier? Why not a comparator?

Comment: @ThePhoton  It depends on where current sensing is done.  If the current sense resistor is on the low side of the motor, then comparator(s) provide a nice solution.  A high side current sensing would still require a current mirror or an InAmp.

Comment: LM311 has input common mode range to Vs-1.2. My go-to in-amp (AD8221) has input common mode range to Vs-1.1. Either one needs some kind of shift to work in this application. But a simple voltage divider would probably be accurate enough for this simple case, and work with either part. But the comparator costs roughly 1/10 what the in-amp does.

Comment: OK, scratch what I said about using a simple voltage divider --- The signal you're looking for is less than 1% of the ~5 V common mode voltage.

Comment: Using an instrumentation amp designed for high side current sensing, like the AD8202, would be appropriate.  Using a current sense amp allows one to use an existing resistor for current sensing, rather than adding a low side sense resistor to use with a comparator.  Multiple approaches could work here.

Answer (score 1):

Remove R1 (replace it with 0 ohms), and connect the nodes labeled "position 1", "position 2" directly to "digital input 1" and "digital input 2".  It will behave exactly as you described.

---

Edit (after resistor values added):

When the switch is at `B`, node `B` will read `5V` and `A` will read the voltage divider from the other branch: `1000 / 1018 * 5V = 4.91V`.  When the switch is at `A`,  node 'A' will read `5V` and `B` will read `1000 / 1004.7 * 5V = 4.98V`.  So, a comparator set at `4.95V` on node `A` will let you distinguish the two cases with just a single digital input.

Comment: R1 cannot be removed as it's part of the circuit. The 3 loads must be where they are. Otherwise, yes, it would be a trivial problem.

Comment: Set its value to 0.  If you can't, you'll have to tell us what its value is.  Our crystal ball is not as clear as you might suspect.

Comment: ok, I added some values. I didn't realize they played a role in a solution. Thanks.

Comment: could you recommend a comparator to use? Would the [LM193A](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/philips/LM193X_4.pdf) work? To set a comparator at `4.95V` you would need a voltage source at `4.95V`   right? would I use a voltage divider to create that? How robust would this solution be? It seems the tolerances are very low. (`0.04V` and `0.03V`). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are kind of nonsensical, but you can meet them with a comparator with a rail-to-rail common mode range:

[image]